# change font size based on original size

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can I do functionality that for example i have input in which I type in value from 1 to 10 and if value is set to 1 all font-size is original and if 10 then font-size for each element changes to 10 * original size ?

please notice that there can me thousands of elements (words) on the site.

performance is crucial

Answer (score 1):

```
document.body.style.fontSize = document.getElementById('myInput').value + 'em';
```

You will need to use relative font sizes throughout the page for this to work.

You should also add some error checking on the value before using it in your CSS.

Comment: He doesn't need to use relative font-sizes, but it surely would be the most performant solution considering it's more or less native.

Comment: If any descendant uses an absolute font size, then it and all its descendants won't be scaled relative to the body. So he does need to use relative font sizes for this solution to work.

Comment: For this solution yes, but it's not necessary to solve his problem. If he need to use fixed font-sizes then my solution will work. It's up to gruber :)

Comment: Sweet, but not jQuery. Still, better to use plain JS when you can, so I like it. But if you want to change font on specific DOM elements, such as this div and that div.. oh and also that bunch of p's and a's, then this one-liner becomes a few more lines and then, IMHO, jQuery makes more sense. More, what if all divs are font 1em, but a tags are 1.5em, then just changing  the font-size to the input value simply doesn't cut it.

Comment: @damo_inc — Since the entire thing keys off relative font sizes, you specifically don't want to apply it explicitly to multiple elements! And if you did want to load all of jQuery then you could express it as `jQuery('body').css('font-size', jQuery('#myInput').val() + 'em')`

Answer (score 0):

I built a small script for you that should do what you ask. Performance shouldn't really be a problem unless you have hundreds of different elements that need to have their font-size changed. How many words that are inside these elements doesn't really matter though.

Here's the script:

```
// Store elements that should change font size
var $changeElements = $(".change-font-size");
// Hook into the keyup event of your input
$("input").keyup(function(){
    // Let's get the multiplier
    var multiplier = parseFloat($(this).val(), 10);
    // Loop through elements
    $changeElements.each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        // Get saved font size from dataset
        var fontSize = $this.data("font-size");
        if (!fontSize) {
            // Get original font size from css and save it to dataset
            // parseInt automagically removes "px"
            fontSize = parseInt($this.css("fontSize"), 10);
            $this.data("font-size", fontSize);
        }
        // Calculate and set the new font size
        $this.css("fontSize", fontSize * multiplier);
    });
});​
```

See [test case on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/Sa5cn/)

Answer (score 0):

You must create a rutine that redefine the size depending on the value of the input, it should be like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Increase Font Size
  $("#increaseFont").change(function(){
    var currentFontSize = $('html').css('font-size');
    var currentFontSizeNum = parseFloat(currentFontSize, 10);
    var newFontSize = currentFontSizeNum*$("#increaseFont").val();
    $('html').css('font-size', newFontSize);
    return false;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/digitalpunch/A6V6e/4/

Basically, select all required elements first, so that you only traverse DOM once and then have a keyup event on your input text box. Tested in Chrome. Works pretty fast - I used lots of text in the fiddle.

Good luck,
Damo

[EDIT:]
Due to public demand here is the code from the fiddle:

```
Size: <input type="text" id="size_var"></input>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipi</p>

$(function() {
    var $p = $('p');
    var origSize = $p.css('font-size');
    origSize = origSize.substr(0, origSize.length - 2);                  
    $('#size_var').keyup(function() {
        var multiplier = $(this).val();
        var size = origSize;
        size *= multiplier;
        $p.css({
            'font-size': size + 'px'
        });
    });
});​
```

[EDIT 2:]

Instead of selecting the p, you can select body or even html tags and change font-size on that. This will cascade down (inheritance) to all children. Just make sure no other children elements override font-size. This way you don't have to iterate across many elements.

Comment: DOM performance issues hit with lots of nodes, not lots of text. You are only modifying one node! (And that isn't a lot of text either!). You also have to change the font size on ever element that you are changing each time you change it, so the 'only once' applies only to discovering the nodes.

Comment: `origSize = origSize.substr(0, origSize.length - 2);` — Is it safe to assume the font size won't be defined as a `%`? This should be handled with `parseFloat`.

Comment: Live demos are great, but they should supplement an answer, not be an essential part of it (i.e. your code should be in the answer itself).

Comment: It's a simple and put together in a few minutes example - don't get so excited.. lol.. and, yes, it's rather obvious that you have to change font size on every element and yes I assumed that the font-size will be in px or em... But thanks for the attention :). I'm sure gruber will appreciate your extra comments.. I did - made me chuckle :)... and I'm going to add the code to the answer. my bad.. apologies

Comment: @Quentin, jQuery normalizes all sizes into pixels. So even if you have percentage or em, jQuery will return the size in px. Check [this test case](http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/VXMsp/)